# 90s TV show or movie about people shooting electricity from their hands

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

All I can remember is it was around 94-95 or maybe earlier. It's about some giants that could throw electric charges from their hands. Also there were people that wore suits that you rub your wrists on some sort of stones and you got this electrical charge in your hand which you could throw.

Comment: This is a good overview, welcome to the site! Can you remember anything specific that happens in the film/TV show though? Any of the plot elements/storylines? What happened in it? Was it live action or animation? If you remember anything else about this please [edit] that detail into your question!

Comment: Note OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [Spellbinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series)) (1995)

> Spellbinder (Polish: Dwa światy (Two worlds)) is a fantasy adventure /science fiction television series, produced by Film Australia and Telewizja Polska in association with the Australian Children's Television Foundation.

I don't remember it having giants, but it specifically does have suits with stones set in the wrist that you rub together to be able to throw balls of electricity. I also remember the effects being better.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4Pdrz_KxhU)

Comment: YES thats it! Thank you so much brings back lots of memories!

Comment: @VladimirGasai -- if this is the correct answer, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question.  And...welcome to the site!